# Windowed Application Visual Studio 2012

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2012

I've tried to create one Blank project from Visual C# Express Edition 2012. When I start my application it's in full screen mode.... I want to create an windowed application.
Where is the option for make the window mode?

P.S.: my OS is Windows 8 RC

Comment: There is no "Visual C# Express Edition 2012."  The three Visual Studio 2012 RC Express SKUs are for Web, Windows 8, and TFS.  Unlike past versions, the Visual Studio 2012 Express SKUs are not language-oriented.

Comment: @James McNellis: Imagine if we had "Visual HTML5, CSS and JavaScript 2012 for Metro-style Applications" and "Visual HTML5, CSS and JavaScript 2012 for Web"...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual Studio Express 2012 RC doesn't yet support desktop development. It will only be available eventually in the upcoming stable release of VS2012, as a separate Express SKU called [Visual Studio Express 2012 for Windows Desktop](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/06/08/visual-studio-express-2012-for-windows-desktop.aspx?).

If you must start desktop development on Windows 8 RP now, you can install Visual C# 2010 Express, which should work the same way on Windows 8 as it always does.

Comment: Or, for the time being, use the Visual Studio 2012 RC Ultimate SKU.  It's freely downloadable.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand about Visual C# Express 2012 you can only create Metro applications with the express version.  If you want to create traditional windowed applications you have to buy the professional edition.  However I think Windows 8 is compatible with older versions of VS Express.

Comment: Also you can use "old" VS 2010 Express.